# need help to check my jquery, it won't work

Tags: jquery, serialization

I try to fix this for a day but I can't, not sure what i Should do...
then I looking for helps, I wondering if someone could help me how to fix it, i stumped already, the problem is when i click the send button the only **"wait"** text appear, even i didn't fill any field then only **'wait' text only...** it seem my jquery doesn't read any field..
for your help i would be appreciate it and thanks.

```
<div class="heading" id="short_msg"> </div>
    <form id="send_to_">
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="150"><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_mail_to; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mail_to" value="<?php echo $mail_to; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="150"><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_subject; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <a onclick="send__to();" class="button"><span><?php echo $button_email_to; ?></span></a>

      </table>
     </form>
```

Below is the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function send__to() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?pe=submit_to&sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>&customer_id=<?php echo $customer_id; ?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#send_to_").serialize(),
    //  data: 'mail_to=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'mail_to\']').val()) + 'subject=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'subject\']').val()),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.success, .warning').remove();
            $('#short_msg').after('<div class="wait"><img src="image/loading_1.gif" alt="" /> <?php echo $text_wait; ?></div>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.wait').remove();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.error) {
                $('#short_msg').after('<div class="warning">' + data.error + '</div>');
            }

            if (data.success) {
                $('#short_msg').after('<div class="success">' + data.success + '</div>');

            //  $('input[name=\'"mail_to\']').val('');
            //  $('input[name=\'subject\']').val('');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;   
}
//--> </script>
```

Comment: You should copy pasta the script which is actually generated, that is, what the __browser__ shows you if you view the page source code. Those `<?php` can be generating code which is the actual source of the problem.

Comment: I suggest using firebug, they have it for firefox and a few other browsers, there is net tab which will show you what type of response your getting back from ajax.

Comment: Hi Trinidad and nick, thanks, I think I need to look for different way, this make me crazy, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

What seems like by far the most likely thing is that your Ajax POST is failing.  If you run it on Firefox, use Firebug to see what gets posted and what gets returned.  Dollars to doughnuts, the Ajax call is *not* returning legal JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the short response... hm I use firebug already but it seem work fine, or perhaps i am not good how to use firebug, is there another idea that similar to my script?

Comment: Bring up Firebug, go to the NET section, press the button on your screen.  One of three things will happen: 1. Nothing: the button was not linked properly to the send_to() function; 2. There is a POST to index.php but the output (click on the word POST and then look at the Response tab) will not be proper JSON: in that case, something is wrong with index.php; or 3. the response is proper JSON: which means there's something wrong with the `success` function in your Javascript.

Comment: hI Malvolio, whe i open firebug and go to NET, but only blank there, but sorry, you said "press the button on your screen" may i know what button i should press? I press the random buttons and PrtScrn/Sysrq but seem nothing different, thanks so much

Comment: I meant -- press the button *that you created*.  The Net tab shows the net communications of the browser but you have to have it open (that's why when you first open it, it's blank: it just started and there haven't been any net communications).  Open the Net tab, and make your program try to do whatever it's supposed to do, watch what happens.